# Send SQL table to another Android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-bluetooth

Sorry if my question is asinine.
I'd like to send the data in SQL table format from one Android device to a second device, so the user in the second device can store and use the received data with my App. What are the best options to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to go down the path of trying to move one sqlite file on a device into the same location on another (I assume that's where you were going with the Bluetooth tag).  Without root access on the destination device, you won't be able to write the file.  From an end (power) user perspective, [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) is a great solution for this, but of course requires root.

If you're looking for "stop on one device, resume on another" functionality for your app, check out [Google Play Services Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames).  It has exactly the functionality you're looking for baked in, and you have to do nothing along the lines of the support infrastructure.

Of course, this is dependent on Google Play Services, so if you're looking to publish on the Amazon App Store (or anything where you're not guaranteed to have the Google stuff available), you may be better off rolling your own web based synchronization infrastructure or subscribing to a service that offers something on par with what Google makes available.